# Mouse position - Cross browser compatibility

Tags: javascript, dom-events, mouse

Working with the mouse within Javascript I have occasionally met the following event attributes:

- **clientX, clientY**
- **layerX, layerY**
- **offsetX, offsetY**
- **pageX, pageY**
- **screenX, screenY**
- **x, y**

I'm wondering what their cross-browser compatibility looks like in general, as I have only found bits and pieces of info that I'm trying to patch up together.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is how jQuery does it :

```
// Calculate pageX/Y if missing and clientX/Y available
if ( event.pageX == null && event.clientX != null ) {
  var doc = document.documentElement, body = document.body;
  event.pageX = event.clientX + (doc && doc.scrollLeft || body && body.scrollLeft || 0) - (doc && doc.clientLeft || body && body.clientLeft || 0);
  event.pageY = event.clientY + (doc && doc.scrollTop  || body && body.scrollTop  || 0) - (doc   && doc.clientTop  || body && body.clientTop  || 0);
}
```

Testing pageX (or pageY) or calculating it from clientX and scrollLeft ans clientLeft

Comment: thanks not the answer I was looking for, but alas... VERY USEFUL! Thanks! =)

Answer (score 1):

You should only rely on `client*`, `movement*`, `screen*`. In MDN Web docs, their compatibility is unknown in most major browsers but they should be considered as support (otherwise, jQuery would be broken in many cases).

`page*` are not supported in Firefox, but they can be calculated from the above properties. Here is the link to the [jQuery implementation](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/d92310050ca7bf0b33825d64e052f9a8809c3e9e/test/data/jquery-1.9.1.js#L3306).

Other properties, `offset*`, `x`, `y`, `layer*` are not standard and you should stop using them if you want to write a high compatibility-level code.

I also made a blog post to summarize all dimensional or position-related properties/methods in Javascript [here](https://transang.me/position-dimension-properties-in-javascript/). Anyone can take a look to see if it is helpful.