# How could I display (x,y) coordinates on image in real-time to the user when the user hovers his mouse over the image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, image

I have a square image/graph on which the user clicks.

Is there a way to display the (x,y) coordinates of the cursor to the user in real-time whenever the user hovers over the image (user does not need to click on the image)?

Comment: Check out the following link for an answer to your question: http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2006/09/02/click-image-and-get-coordinates-with-javascript/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here you go:

HTML:

```
<img class="coords" src="http://i.imgur.com/bhvpy.png">
```

JavaScript:

```
var tooltip = $( '<div id="tooltip">' ).appendTo( 'body' )[0];

$( '.coords' ).
    each(function () {
        var pos = $( this ).position(),
            top = pos.top,
            left = pos.left,
            width = $( this ).width(),
            height = $( this ).height();

        $( this ).
            mousemove(function ( e ) {
                var x, y;

                x = ( ( e.clientX - left ) / width ).toFixed( 1 ),
                y = ( ( height - ( e.clientY - top ) ) / height ).toFixed( 1 );

                $( tooltip ).text( x + ', ' + y ).css({
                    left: e.clientX - 30,
                    top: e.clientY - 30
                }).show();
            }).
            mouseleave(function () {
                $( tooltip ).hide();
            }); 
    });
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/pSVXz/12/

With my updated code, you can have multiple images with this functionality - just add the class `"coords"` to the images.

Note: This code has to be inside the `load` handler (instead of the `ready`) handler, because we have to read the image's dimensions which we can only do for fully loaded images.

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there a way to have the coords displayed just "above" the cursor, in effect following the cursor around?

Comment: Appreciate it. This is the image I am using: http://i.imgur.com/bhvpy.png - I see that the coords are taken from the height/width of the image, and every coordinate is incremented by a pixel. Is there a way to "normalize" this such as to use a scale of 0-10, with 0.1 increments on both the x and y axes, regardless of image size?

Answer (score 8):

This should do it:

**HTML**

```
<img id="the_image" src="http://placekitten.com/200/200" />
<div id="coords"></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$image = $('#the_image');
imgPos = [
    $image.offset().left,
    $image.offset().top,
    $image.offset().left + $image.outerWidth(),
    $image.offset().top + $image.outerHeight()
];

$image.mousemove(function(e){
  $('#coords').html((e.pageX-imgPos[0]) +', '+ (e.pageY-imgPos[1]));
});
```

**DEMO** (updated): http://jsfiddle.net/az8Uu/2/

Note: [Throttling](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/) the mousemove handler would be a good idea too, to avoid calling the function every 4 milliseconds.

Comment: I'm not a native English speaker ... What does "throttling" mean in that context ? (the definitions I've found seem irrelevant)
EDIT: my bad, I found an explanation : http://remysharp.com/2010/07/21/throttling-function-calls/

Comment: I've added a link - it limits the 'rate of fire' so the event handler is only called once per N milliseconds, ie. so the coords only update 5-10 times per second instead of 250 times per second (which is just wasteful and could potentially slow down your app)

Comment: @tsimbalar The idea is to call the handler only at the end of the user activity. For instance, if the user moved the mouse for a second, the mousemove handler is invoked only once at the end (instead of every 20ms during the mouse movement).

Comment: @Šime: actually what you are describing is debouncing ;)

Comment: Fantastic. This is why I love SO, this is very helpful. Is there a way to have the coords displayed just "above" the cursor, in effect following the cursor around?

Comment: Sure, you can just add `$('#coords').css({left: (e.pageX-imgPos[0]), top: (e.pageY-imgPos[1])})` (make sure #coords is positioned absolutely)

Comment: Ok, will have to play around with it. I said this in a comment above: This is the image I am using: i.imgur.com/bhvpy.png - I see that the coords are taken from the height/width of the image, and every coordinate is incremented by a pixel. Is there a way to "normalize" this such as to use a scale of 0-10, with 0.10 increments on both the x and y axes, regardless of image size?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your requirements, something based on :

```
$("img").mousemove(function(e) {
    console.log(e.layerX + ", " + e.layerY);
});
```

Comment: Based on comments - have changed pageX/pageY to layerX / layerY - which does not require you to remove offset()

Comment: Sadly, layerX / layerY are not likely to work cross-browser at all - Quirksmode doesn't include them in their compatibility table (http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html#mousepos), jQuery specifically does not normalize it (http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) and others have mentioned issues with it here on SO (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3343384/mouse-position-cross-browser-compatibility-javascript)