# Unable to get mouse coordinates relative to document in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a small problem,  i need to get mouse co-ordinates when user clicks on page..
Here I need to get position relative to document(page) nor relative to found..

```
After browsing a day , i found one solution i.e., window.event.pageY. 
but its working only for Chrome.. not in IE, not Firefox.
```

Can any one help me on this...If solution is in javascript, then usefull for me..

An example given will be appreciated..

thanks.
Rajesh

Answer (score 0):

You could used jQuery's normalized event object with pageX/pageY. See the example code in their [SDK](http://api.jquery.com/event.pageX/).

EDIT: For a pure js solution, try this post -  [Mouse position - Cross browser compatibility - Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3343384/mouse-position-cross-browser-compatibility-javascript)

[QuirksMode](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html) is always helpful too.

Comment: @RajeshVaddepally: jQuery is just a JavaScript library. It should work in all somewhat-recent browsers.

Comment: The jQuery SDK example works for me in IE8 too. What browser is it failing in? I added a link above for a possible non-JQuery solution.