# HTML5 Video Control and Browser Detection with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, browser-detection

Im trying to modify the script that allows me to navigate through my video based on either Chrome or Firefox.

I've noticed that using the offsetX function works well in Chrome but not at all in Firefox. And using the "e.pageX-bar.offsetLeft" worked for me in Firefox. Therefore I need a way to determine which to use depending on browser.

```
function move(e){
    if (navigator.userAgent.search("Chrome") >= 0){
        if(!media.paused && !media.ended){
                var mouseX= e.offsetX;
                newTime=((mouseX*media.duration)/barSize);
                media.currentTime=newTime;
                progress.style.width=mouseX+'px';
            }
    }
    else if (navigator.userAgent.search("Firefox") >= 0){
        if(!media.paused && !media.ended){
                var mouseX= e.pageX-bar.offsetLeft;
                newTime=((mouseX*media.duration)/barSize);
                media.currentTime=newTime;
                progress.style.width=mouseX+'px';
            }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Have you seen [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/)?

Comment: I've seen it mentioned before but im not sure what it is or does even after quickly reading over the site.

Comment: Read through http://modernizr.com/docs/.

Comment: I don't think Modernizr won't be of any help here (although I'd recommend using it for other reasons, but feature detection won't help you solve your question here). I guess you should find a way of scripting your mouse position calculation in a cross browser way. A look at the source of the JS library of your choice might be a good starting point: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3343384/mouse-position-cross-browser-compatibility-javascript

Comment: Turns out what I have here works pretty well except for FF the seekbar will only work in fullscreen. http://www3.carleton.ca/clubs/sissa/html5/video.html